# Lost messages with TCPServer

Tags: ruby, multithreading, tcp

For a project I need to implement a TCP Server. But after a while I have seen that sometimes I am loosing messages. It was a surprise for me because I have always been told that TCP do not loose packets.

So I have written two little scripts to test the reception of the messages and I have seen that I am losing some even when it is the simplest code I can do.

To make the example simple I am creating a different thread for each connection, this will not be the case with my production code (it will be a thread pool that works like NGNIX).

Here is the code of the server:

```
require 'socket'
require 'thread'
require 'timeout'

LIMIT = 100

def get_message (client)
  message = 'nothing'
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(1) do
      message = client.gets
    end
  rescue
    message = 'timeout'
  end
  unless message == nil
    message.chomp!
  end
  message
end


server = TCPServer.new(9000)
queue_message, queue_empty, queue_nil, queue_nothing, queue_timeout  = Queue.new, Queue.new, Queue.new, Queue.new, Queue.new
threads = []

(1..LIMIT).each do
  threads << Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    counter = 0
    while counter != LIMIT do
      message = get_message(client)
      case message
        when nil
          queue_nil << message
          break
        when ''
          queue_empty << message
        when 'nothing'
          queue_nothing << message
        when 'timeout'
          queue_timeout << message
        else
          queue_message << message
          counter += 1
      end
    end
    client.close
  end
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}
size = queue_message.size
counter = 0
check = Array.new(LIMIT){Array.new(LIMIT)}
until queue_message.empty?
  message = queue_message.pop.split '::'
  check[message[0].to_i][message[1].to_i] = 1
end
(0..LIMIT - 1).each do |i|
  (0..LIMIT - 1).each do |j|
    if check[i][j] == nil
      puts "#{j}::#{i}"
      counter += 1
    end
  end
end
puts '--------------------------------------'
puts 'Threads are finished'
puts "messages: #{size}"
puts "missing: #{counter}"
puts "nil: #{queue_nil.size}"
puts "empty: #{queue_empty.size}"
puts "nothing: #{queue_nothing.size}"
puts "timeout: #{queue_timeout.size}"
puts '--------------------------------------'
```

And this is the code of the clients:

```
require 'socket'

LIMIT = 100

def get_message (client)
  message = ''
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(GETS_TIMEOUT_SPECS) do
      message = client.gets
    end
    unless message == nil
      message.chop!
    end
  end
  message
end

threads = []
client = []
(0..LIMIT - 1).each do |j|
  threads << Thread.new do
    client[j] = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 9000)
    (0..LIMIT - 1).each do |i|
      message = "#{j}::#{i}"
      client[j].puts message
      puts message
      sleep 1
    end
    client[j].close
  end
end

threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

Finally this is an output example that I got:

```
--------------------------------------
Threads are finished
messages: 8230
missing: 1770
nil: 100
empty: 557
nothing: 0
timeout: 2258
--------------------------------------
```

Sometimes there is no losses at all.
So where does my messages got lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing most of TCPSocket methods, I have found that I can use recv intsead of gets and do not lost any messages.
In addition to that I do not need anymore to use timeout.

Here is how I do read from the socket:

```
def get_message (client)
    message = ''
    while 1 do
        char = client.recv(8)
        message += char
        if char.length < 8
            break
        end
    end
    unless message == nil
        message.chomp!
    end
    message
end
```

Comment: Did you find out why `gets` would loose messages?

Comment: gets is waiting for a "\n" at the end of the message, which is not always the case.